# Helm list tries to connect to localhost rather than Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster running. All pods are running. This is a windows machine with minikube on it.

However `helm ls --debug` gives following error

```
helm ls --debug
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '57209'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:57209"

Error: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Cluster information

```
kubectl.exe cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://135.250.128.98:8443

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

kubectl service

```
kubectl.exe get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   3h
```

Dashboard is accessible at `http://135.250.128.98:30000`

kube configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: C:\Users\abc\.minikube\ca.crt
    server: https://135.250.128.98:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate: C:\Users\abc\.minikube\client.crt
    client-key: C:\Users\abc\.minikube\client.key
```

Is there a solution? Most online resource says cluster is misconfigured. But not sure what is misconfigured and how to solve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What worked for me when I was facing the same issue was changing `automountServiceAccountToken` to `true`.

Use the following command to edit the tiller-deploy

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system edit deployment/tiller-deploy
```

And change `automountServiceAccountToken` to `true`

Comment: to apply this patch non-interactively, this worked for me: `kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"automountServiceAccountToken":true}}}}'`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced that problem and found an explanation on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/3816).

In this case, the preferable method to make it work is to rebuild the docker container with missing environment variable. These lines should build a new image:

```
cat << eof > Dockerfile 
FROM gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.3.1 
ENV KUBERNETES_MASTER XX.XX.XX.XX:8080 
eof 

docker build -t tiller:latest .
```

Please substitute XX.XX.XX.XX with your Kubernetes Master IP address.